# How to sort data with ng-click after already loaded with ng-click angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I'm trying to get the information in the table to change using ng-click. I have the functions that load and sort and work correctly,
 but I'm not able to switch between the two. By this I mean, if I click
 load, I can't sort after and vice versa. I think it's because I reset
 countries with each click, but I'm not sure how to recognize them both
 if I have them in different variable using ng-repeat. Help Please!!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en" ng-app="frontendTest">
      <head>
        <title>Frontend Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js" ></script>
      </head>
      <body ng-controller="CountriesController as countries">

        <header>
          <h1>Frontend Test</h1>  
          <div></div>
        </header>

        <section class="buttons">
          <input type="button" value="Load Countries" ng-click="load()">
          <input type="button" value="Sort Countries" ng-click="sort()">
        </section>

        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="col-md-6">Name</th>
              <th class="col-md-6">Population</th>
            </tr> 
          </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat="country in countries track by $index" >            
             <td class="col-sm-6">{{country.country}}</td>
             <td  class="col-sm-6">{{country.population}}</td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>                        
      </body>
    </html>

angular
  .module("frontendTest",[])
  .controller("CountriesController", CountriesController);

  CountriesController.inject =['$scope'];

  function CountriesController($scope){

    $scope.data = 
    [
      {"country" : "Aruba", "population" : 103000},
      {"country" : "Afghanistan", "population" : 22720000},
      {"country" : "Angola", "population" : 12878000},
      {"country" : "Anguilla", "population" : 8000},
      {"country" : "Albania", "population" : 3401200},
      {"country" : "Andorra", "population" : 78000},
      {"country" : "Netherlands Antilles", "population" : 217000},
      {"country" : "Zimbabwe", "population" : 11669000}
    ];

    $scope.countries= [];
    $scope.sorted = [];
    $scope.loaded = false;

    $scope.load = function (){
      //show all CountriesController and population
      console.log("LOAD");
      $scope.loaded = true;
      for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys($scope.data).length; i++){
        $scope.countries.push($scope.data[i]);
        // console.log($scope.countries);
      }
    }

    $scope.sort = function (){
      // if($scope.loaded === true){
      console.log("SORT");
      $scope.sortByCountry = $scope.data.slice(0);  
      $scope.sortByCountry.sort(function(a,b){
        //isolate countries and population sort by name            
        var x = a.country;
        var y = b.country;

        return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
      });

      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.sortByCountry.length; i++){
        // console.log($scope.sortByCountry[i]);  
        $scope.countries.push($scope.sortByCountry[i]);
        console.log($scope.sortByCountry[i]);

      } 
      // }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you're appending to existing array when you can sort it and leave as is. I've simplified your code and it should work as you wanted to. You can also use [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) helper from AngularJS which should reduce an amount of code.

```js
angular
  .module("frontendTest",[])
  .controller("CountriesController", CountriesController);

  CountriesController.inject =['$scope'];

function CountriesController($scope){

   $scope.data = 
   [
  {"country" : "Aruba", "population" : 103000},
  {"country" : "Afghanistan", "population" : 22720000},
  {"country" : "Angola", "population" : 12878000},
  {"country" : "Anguilla", "population" : 8000},
  {"country" : "Albania", "population" : 3401200},
  {"country" : "Andorra", "population" : 78000},
  {"country" : "Netherlands Antilles", "population" : 217000},
  {"country" : "Zimbabwe", "population" : 11669000}
  ];

  $scope.countries= [];
  $scope.sorted = [];
  $scope.loaded = false;

  $scope.load = function (){
    $scope.loaded = true;
    // Cloning data
    $scope.countries = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.data));
  }



  $scope.sort = function (){
    if($scope.loaded === true){ 
      $scope.countries.sort(function(a,b){
        var x = a.country;
        var y = b.country;

        return x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="frontendTest" ng-controller="CountriesController as countries">

        <header>
          <h1>Frontend Test</h1>  
          <div></div>
        </header>

        <section class="buttons">
          <input type="button" value="Load Countries" ng-click="load()">
          <input type="button" value="Sort Countries" ng-click="sort()">
        </section>


        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="col-md-6">Name</th>
              <th class="col-md-6">Population</th>
            </tr> 
          </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat="country in countries track by $index" >

             <td class="col-sm-6">{{country.country}}</td>
             <td  class="col-sm-6">{{country.population}}</td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>


        </body>
```

Comment: Ok, makes complete sense. I realized that I was repeating myself, but I couldn't figure out how to keep the data and manipulate it for the sort function. I'll also check out the orderby and give it a go. Thank you so much!